# Can you set SQL to automatically 'Flush hosts;' on a server? How?

Tags: sql, workbench

Can you set SQL to automatically 'Flush hosts;' on a server? How?

Comment: What exactly is "flush hosts"? That is not a standard SQL statement. Which DBMS are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy to do and the most popular way is to run a cron job containing the `Flush Hosts` command on your server. You may set it run at 3a.m everyday.
Write a simple php script( you may write it in another language ):

```
<?php
    $username="xxxxxxx";
    $password="xxxxxx";
    $dbname="xxxxxx";
    $dbhost="xxxxx.xxxxx.com";
    $query="Flush hosts";
    mysqli_connect($dbhost,$username,$password);
    mysqli_select_db($dbname) or die(" Unable to select database");
    mysqli_query($query);
    mysqli_close();
?>
```

And Cron job( running every hour ):

```
# crontab -e
00 * * * * php /home/path/YOUR_SCRIPT.php
```

Note `php` refers to your php path and `YOUR_SCRIPT` is your file path.

Good Luck